# Android : AlarmManager premature trigger (Min API 14)

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

i have create a service that will be trigger by AlarmManager with custom / manual time. if i have set AlarmManager will be run at 02.15 PM, sometimes its run at 02.10 or before the time set. anyone can help me.

this is my code to set time :

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int minute = TimerFormatHelper.getMinute();    
    now.set(Calendar.HOUR, now.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return now.getTimeInMillis();
    //it will return timestamp for time that set
```

and this the code to set Alarm :

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)       getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long startTime = HereTimestampThatGenerateBefore;
    Intent intentApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TheServiceHere.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentApp = PendingIntent
            .getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime,
            pendingIntentApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `alarmManager.setExact()` method in place of `alarManager.set()`

As per docs:

> This method is like set() but does not permit the OS to adjust the
>   delivery time. The alarm will be delivered as nearly as possible to
>   the requested trigger time. Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm
>   delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize
>   wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications
>   which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long,
>   PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications
>   whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    alarmManager.setExact(...);
} else {
    alarmManager.set(...);
}
```

Comment: Just remember that SetExact() will reduce the OS's ability to minimize battery use.

Comment: i cant use setExact because min API must 19 and my app min API is 14

Comment: Unfortunately setExact() is only available for api 19+ so you'll have to use set() for 14 through 18 which will be inexact. I will edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the  `now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);` to trigger the alarm at 1 or 2 seconds.`now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);`

If the Alarm is set at 2:15 then this will trigger as soon as the time reaches 2:15:1 .

Comment: That is the problem don't set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

instead of :

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime,
        pendingIntentApp);
```

And here targetCal comes from the TimePickerDialog

```
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                                  int selectedMinute) {

                Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                setAlarm(calSet);

            }
        };
```

And you can set alarm in SetAlarm method where you can find your receiver

```
  private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    mSetTime.setText(
            "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

}